# Which Liferay permissions do I need to set to create site pages?

Tags: permissions, liferay

We have a function to allow a user to create a new organization in our portal. When this happens we are trying to set up the site pages using:

```
SitesUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypesLinks(siteGroup, 0L, layoutSetPrototypeId, false, true);
```

This seems to work when the user is an admin, but when a non-admin user tries we get this error:

```
12:28:18,104 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-214][WorkflowEditorController:120] In check():
com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.GroupPermissionImpl.check(GroupPermissionImpl.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.GroupPermissionUtil.check(GroupPermissionUtil.java:39)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutSetServiceImpl.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(LayoutSetServiceImpl.java:61)
```

I assume the issue is with permissions. I am trying to find the correct permission to assign to the organization role given to the users who can create organizations, but I can't figure out which permission it is. I have tried adding pretty much all the site permissions through the control panels, and I have tried add Resourcepermissions programmatically using:

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(org.getCompanyId(), LayoutSetPrototype.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_GROUP_TEMPLATE, String.valueOf(layoutSetPrototypeId), role.getRoleId(), ActionKeys.UPDATE);
```

Nothing seems to make a difference. Does anyone know exactly which permission I need to be granting?

Comment: Where did you put the SitesUtil call? It _might_ be that this happens _before_ the user is then made member of the resulting organization/site, thus site-specific permissions wouldn't be available yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Olaf. I don't think that's what's happening; in the "real" version of the code the user is added to the organization and given the owner role just before the command to set up the site pages is called, and in my tests I'm logged in as a user who is already a member with the owner role and just trying to set up the site pages.